# PUT FormData laravel. Не принимаются данные

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, vue.js, put

Отправляю данные серверу для обновления с помощью метода PUT. Данные отправляю с помощью FormData. Данные отправляются, это видно в Chrome, но сервер не видет данные.

```
$request = $request->all()
```

С методом POST все работает нормально. Отправляю текстовые данные и файл

Как мне обновить данные? Переделывать роуты под метод POST?

**UPD**

В Controller я пока что, просто пытаюсь получить ответ от сервера

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request = $request->all();
        dd($request);
}
```

Этот способ работает, если отправлять данные в формате POST, то все нормально работает. Использую вместо vue-resource **axios**

```
save() {
                var vm = this
                var form = document.querySelector('form');
                var formdata = new FormData(form)
                axios[this.method](this.store, formdata)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        if (response.data.saved) {
                            vm.$router.push(vm.redirect)
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    })
            }
```

Кстати вот, если я напишу `$reqyest->getContent()`, то я получу данные в таком формате, но как их обрабатывать?

```
b"""
------WebKitFormBoundaryFEIpstOEw72VwaAe\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"\r\n
\r\n
Moscow\r\n
------WebKitFormBoundaryFEIpstOEw72VwaAe\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="cost"\r\n
\r\n
1.00\r\n
------WebKitFormBoundaryFEIpstOEw72VwaAe\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="picture"; filename="angel.png"\r\n
Content-Type: image/png\r\n
\r\n
...HIDEN...
------WebKitFormBoundaryFEIpstOEw72VwaAe\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"\r\n
\r\n
<p>1</p>\r\n
\r\n
------WebKitFormBoundaryFEIpstOEw72VwaAe--\r\n
"""
```

Comment: Приведи пример своих маршрутов и контроллеров и еще сделай php artisan route:list, посмотри есть ли у тебя маршрут

Comment: @Orange_shadow, Маршрут есть Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/'], function ()
{
    Route::resource('basket', 'BasketController');
    Route::resource('city', 'CityController'); });

Comment: а далее ? как обрабатываешь в контроллере ? , и желательно внеси изменения в вопрос, и еще такой вопрос ты это в фале routes/web.php делаешь же  tocken передаешь ? какой ответ от сервера идет ?

Comment: И еще вопрос если ты vue.js используешь то ты и vue resource тоже используешь или нет  ?

Comment: @Orange_shadow, обновил

Comment: А можешь попробовать вместо FormData(from) сделать form. serialize(), правда это метод jquery

Comment: Попробуй vue resourece, ради интереса

Comment: @Orange_shadow, нет все равно данные не  видно командой

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51871/discussion-between-orange-shadow-and-blanry).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак имеем: данные FormData нужно отправить методом пост, но добавить в форму

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT">
```

или перед отправкой сделать так

```
formData = new FormData(form)
formData.append("_method", "PUT");
```